# What would a lunar eclipse look like from the surface of the moon?

Tags: the-moon

The Earth would have a thin red ring around it, where sunlight is scattered by the atmosphere, right? Would the corona of the sun be very visible?

Answer (score 23):

It would look a lot like this:

[image: kayuga probe eclipse]

These images were taken by the [SELENE (Kaguya) probe](http://www.kaguya.jaxa.jp/index_e.htm) in Feb 2009 during a penumbral eclipse. They were not taken from the surface, but from a 50km orbit. Because of the negligible atmosphere on the moon, I assume there wouldn't be much difference. You can find other images in [their gallery](http://wms1.wms.selene.darts.isas.jaxa.jp/selene_viewer/en/observation_mission/2009/02/).

You can also see this in video form, both on the [JAXA site](http://wms.selene.darts.isas.jaxa.jp/selene_viewer/en/observation_mission/hdtv/059/diamond_ring_earth.html) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zq0ptByQrcg).

Comment: All links are now dead except one video, so I've embedded a viewer for it. This is an excellent example of the fact that **links rot** and why **link-only answers are strongly discouraged!**

Comment: @uhoh - but thanks for going to the trouble: a glorious view. Now I'll have "Also Sprach Zarathustra" as an earworm for the day...

Comment: @TomGoodfellow I was confused momentarily (I didn't hear anything) but then remembered a very special, very Kubrick movie from 1968 ;-)

Answer (score 17):

NASA have already produced their impression of what it is likely to look like. [Sciencenotes.org](http://sciencenotes.org/tag/lunar-eclipse/) has this picture from NASA's Scientific Visualization Studio

[image]

And if you want to see a full animation, [NASA Scientific Visualization Studio also has this](http://svs.gsfc.nasa.gov/vis/a000000/a004100/a004157/index.html).

From their work it appears the corona **would** be very visible as with the Earth blocking out all direct light, the eye will be able to make out the faint corona. It is, after all, the principle by which various solar observatories work. The red ring around the Earth also should be obvious - it is the sun's light being refracted through the Earth's atmosphere.

Comment: Interesting. It happens that the apparent size of the sun and the moon is very similar from Earth, which is why Earth-based solar eclipses look as they do; from the moon, the Earth should appear four times the size of the sun, so I would have expected to see almost no evidence of the sun in the moon-based solar eclipse.

Comment: It is always interesting to me how many people here seem to have all these links i don't find on my own that they come up with in minutes.

Comment: Is it the corona, or is it the sun's light being bent by the earth's atmosphere?

Comment: The redness of the moon when it is in the Earth's penumbra is because of the red light of a 'ring of sunsets and sunrises' around the limbs of the Earth.

Comment: I suppose if there was a real solar flare during the eclipse, that would be pretty visible? And probably gorgeous...

Comment: Excuse my mistake above - the moon is red when it is in the [umbra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_eclipse#Types_of_lunar_eclipse) - the central, darkest part of the shadow. The penumbra is the lighter shadow around that.

Comment: I've always thought it was a curious coincidence that the size of the Moon was just right to cover the Sun when humans were becoming interested in the mechanics of it. It would've looked larger much earlier, and it'll look smaller in the future. We evolved at the right time.

Comment: But then again, humans will find patterns in everything. If you look closely, the sizes aren't even an exact match. They are just close enough :-)

Answer (score 4):

I did find this artist's interpretation and a discussion at [Earthsky](http://en.es-static.us/upl/2011/06/lunar_eclipse_from_moon_550.jpg)

[image: Eclipse of the moon as seen from the lunar surface]

Comment: I wonder if this might be more realistic. It shows the corona and a very thin red ring, it strikes me as more to scale but i don't know.

Comment: I'm guessing the NASA one is more likely. I think while the corona is large, it is also very faint as you get further from the sun.